# Плавное увеличение частоты выполнения

Tags: c++, arduino

Пишу код на ардуино, раз в 1 мс подаю ток на нужный мне пин пусть это делает функция pin()

```
function pin(){
  digitalWrite(x,HIGH); delay(1); digitalWrite(x,LOW); 
}

bool fade = true;

byte PAUSE_FADE = 255;
long lastFade = 0;
function show(bool fade0 = false){
   if(fade0) fade = fade0;
   if(fade){
      if ((millis() - lastFade) > PAUSE_FADE){
         lastFade = millis();
         PAUSE_FADE--;
         pin();
         if(PAUSE_FADE == 0) {
           fade = false;
           PAUSE_FADE = 255;
         }
      }else delay(1);
   }else pin();
}
```

Необходимо записать в глобальную переменную данные для активности Fade(плавной подачи импульса).

Долгий delay() использовать нельзя.

Задача в том чтобы при изменении какого то значения я мог вызвать функцию show(true) с параметром true один раз, то в дальнейшем импульсы подавались реже чем раз в 1мс (появлялись пропуски) и с течением времени плавное увеличение частоты выполнения функции pin(); , но тем неменее функция show() без параметров вызывается в цикле программы.

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос?

Comment: Ну во-первых в этом коде явно есть опечатка, так как переменной `fade0` не объявлено.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Согласен, мне нужно чтобы это работало по задумке... не могу сообразить как это реализовать в коде.

Comment: Когда `PAUSE_FADE` дойдет до нуля будет переполнение.

Comment: можно a) условие "if ((millis() - lastFade) > PAUSE_FADE)" вынести в основной цикл и контролировать оттуда б) подвесить это дело на прерывание по таймеру.

Comment: Таймер без внешних библиотек? Как вы предлагаете реализовать? Может так будет более быстрое выполнение задач и меньшая нагрузка на чип? Код очень большой всё тестируется на атмега 328P, в будущем хотелось бы перейти на 168P, кварц на 8 МГц. Чем меньше нагрузка и потребление тем лучше. Я понимаю Вы такого плана решение предлагаете? https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=435154.0 Такого рода таймеры для меня тёмный лес...

Comment: Я 4 раза поочередно подаю импульсы поэтому у меня 4 разных таймера в массиве и нет смысла выносить его в основной цикл программы (вариант а), у меня это работает, но кажется нужно разбираться с таймерами, как Вы и предложили. Надеюсь конечно до этого не дойдёт.

Comment: Не видя всей картины сложно что-то советовать, но вынести условие в основной цикл наверняка будет легче.... Да, таймеры такого рода с работой на прямую.... Их в мегах 2-3 штуки, но какой-то ЕМНИП используют сами библиотеки arduino для своих грязных дел. Инструмент мощный, но есть много подводных камней. Если остальной код написан плохо, то, возможно, придётся его практически полностью переписать только чтобы внедрить его. Алгоритм работы как описан ниже в ответе...

Comment: @NickSan По поводу снижения энергопотребления при простое — это отдельная большая тема, но в принципе вещь достижимая, хотя если питаешься от сети, то это экономия на спичках ИМХО. Идея в том, чтобы в основном цикле переходить в состояние с пониженным энергопотреблением, а потом просыпаться по таймеру или внешнему прерыванию.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Просыпаться не нужно, там мосфет и неопиксели (работает постоянно). Так что наврядли на чем то получится сэкономить, но спасибо за ответ. На счет ответа ниже подразумевается attachInterrupt(interrupt, function, mode) или что? я немного не понимаю о чем речь в силу опыта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать прерывание по таймеру.

Задаём квант приращения. Например, 1 мс. Удобно, если он будет равен времени высокого уровня на пине.

Задаём минимальное и максимальное время между импульсами.

Задаём флаг состояния: 0 - ничего не делать, 1 - увеличивать время, -1 - уменьшать.

Устанавливаем время срабатывания таймера, равное кванту приращения.

Разрешаем прерывания.

В обработчике прерывания от таймера проверяем состояние и либо увеличиваем, либо уменьшаем время, либо ничего не делаем. И переводим пин в высокий или низкий уровень, в зависимости от того, в каком он состоянии сейчас (это вместо вызова функции pin()).

Теперь можно из основного цикла скетча вызывать фейды, меняя состояние переменной состояния.

Comment: Какой "квант приращения"? Вы об этом http://arduino.ru/Reference/AttachInterrupt ? Цифровой порт 2 уже занят.

Comment: Квант (от лат. quantum — «сколько») — неделимая порция какой-либо величины.